# Wix directory reference a registry value

Tags: wix, registry

I am writing an installer which needs to lookup the installation directory from a registry value.

I am using the property to lookup the registry and the component group refers that property. But the component group doesn't seem to be picking up directory from the property. Is there a better way to do it?

Cheers..

Comment: You should provide more detail. I assume you are doing a registrysearch that sets a directory property, so show your source, and make sure your search is going to the proper registry, either 32-bit or 64-bit. A verbose log will show if the property is being set but there's something wrong later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are doing something like that :

```
<Property Id="MY_PATHNAME" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="My_Path_Signature" Root="HKLM"
    Key="$(var.My_Key)" Name="PathName" Type="directory">
  </RegistrySearch>
</Property>
```

then you're trying to retrieve the value of "MY_PATHNAME"...

In case the installer decides not to set the property correctly , you can generate a log from the command line :

```
msiexec /i MyInstaller.msi /l*v MyLog.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it working, it was not setting it properly, log helped.